# How to make soft maximum numeric stable and avoid overflow?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

I'm talking about this function. 
$$
\mathcal{S}_{\alpha}\left(\left\{x_i\right\}_{i=1}^{n}\right) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i e^{\alpha x_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{\alpha x_i}}
$$

In order to avoid to over flow such as in the case of Softmax classification, I subtracted the maximum value from each of the inputs. but the results are all negatives and this doesn't give me the right maximum answer what ever the alpha I'm using.

Is there any way I could adapt this function on not going to overflow when my input is large. knowing that my inputs might vary from -inf to +inf ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M=\max(x_i)$ and divide both the numerator and denominator by $e^{\alpha M}$. This results in

$$\mathcal{S}_{\alpha}\left(\left\{x_i\right\}_{i=1}^{n}\right) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i e^{\alpha (x_i-M)}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{\alpha (x_i-M)}}$$

where all values of the exponential function are bounded by $1$.

Your mistake was in subtracting $M$ everywhere. It only  needs to be subtracted in the exponents.